# git remote with distinct pull/push urls how to avoid fetch step after push?

Tags: git

My config looks like this

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = https://github.com/theteam/foo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
    pushurl = https://github.com/me/foo.git
[remote "myfork"]
    url = https://github.com/me/foo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/myfork/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = upstream
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

indeed I have push access to the `theteam/foo.git` repo but I want to be fully certain not to make there accidental pushes. Hence the pushurl is configured to use my own account, where `foo.git` is cloned.

Problem is that when I do `git pull` (local master branch gets updated from upstream repo), then `git push` (my own clone gets updated), I still need a `git fetch myfork`, else my local `/remote/myfork` is not updated. And this sometimes surprises me because `git show remote myfork` tells me everying is up-to-date.

What is missing in my config so that doing `git push` avoids the `git fetch myfork` subsequent step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since upstream remote does not know about remotes/myfork refspec, it cannot update such tracking referdnces. (I wonder if it updates remotes/upstream/master)

*probably* what you are looking for is branch.*name*.pushRemote:

```
...
[branch "master"]
 remote = upstream
 pushRemote = myfork
 ...
```

then push will know the correct remote context

ps: to me looks working (git-2.0.0):

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --no-color
2a1baf2 (HEAD, master) r1
4e9c27d (upstream/master, upstream/HEAD, origin/master) u2
deb02c0 u1
$ cat .git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "upstream"]
        url = /home/nemo/so2/upstream
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
        pushurl = ../origin/
[branch "master"]
        remote = upstream
        pushRemote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
        url = ../origin/
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[push]
        default = simple
$ git push
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 170 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../origin/
   4e9c27d..2a1baf2  master -> master
$ git log --oneline --decorate --no-color
2a1baf2 (HEAD, origin/master, master) r1
4e9c27d (upstream/master, upstream/HEAD) u2
deb02c0 u1
$
```

Comment: I didn't know about `pushRemote`! unfortunately in the test I just did I had to use `pushRemote = https://github.com/me/foo.git` for the `push` to work, and then `myfork/master` was not updated (from checking with `git rev-parse`, as `git remote show myfork` misleadingly seems to say everything is up-to-date, but this is from misinterpreting what it outputs) Situation is same as with using `pushurl`.

Comment: I added example to answer

Comment: +1 thank you on your insistence I first tried with pushRemote set to a location on my disk as in your added example, and it worked, then I again tested with my github account and remote "myfork", and it worked. I have no idea how I got confused the first time. Note: I have my ``.git/config`` without a pushurl configured now for remote "upstream". I juste make sure that my branches which have this as remote also have the pushRemote.

Comment: well on second thoughts I will leave the "pushurl" configured for upstream, I don't want to risk any wrong push (sometimes things can get copy-pasted to command line one never knows...)

Comment: Just an update for the passers-by: ``pushRemote`` first made it into git with release 1.8.3, and some bug was fixed at 2.0.0. Be careful before using for real that on earlier git than 1.8.3 the ``pushRemote`` will simply be ignored (I just experienced it because for some reason on some place I have 1.7.9 only)